# How do I use the mod function?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, modulo

A vector of 30 elements is given.

```
Numbers=1:30;
```

How do I write a loop that prints out the multiples of 3 in that vector and the numbers that aren't multiples of 3?

Comment: `Numbers(~mod(Numbers,3))` will give the multiples. You can figure out the non.multiples

Comment: In Matlab you don't need a loop for this, `mod` can accept the entire vector. Have a look at [the docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same vein of what Luis Mendo said, you could do it this way:

```
Numbers = 1:30;
Numbers(~mod(Numbers,3))
Numbers(~mod(Numbers,3)==0)
```